# How to change the background color of a UILabel with swift

Tags: swift3, label, xcode8, background-color

In my Xcode project, I want to change/set the background color of a label using Swift. How can I do that simply?

I have this, but it only works for buttons.

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 159/255, blue: 184/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Updated for swift 3:

1] if you want to change the UILabel background color, then used below simple lines of code:

```
yourLabelName.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

**Note:-** You can also be used different types of standard colors, UIColor.white, UIColor.red...

2] If you want to change the UILabel text color, then used below simple lines of code:

```
   yourLabelName.textColor = UIColor.red
```

// Enjoy Coding...!

Answer (score 7):

You can do that in this way

```
label.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 159/255, blue: 184/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Comment: this is working but the problem for me is that my label size in larger than text and I just want to change text background color

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4.0/3.0:**

```
<your label name>.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

**SWIFT 2.0:**

```
<your label name>.backgroundColor = UIColor.green()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the UILabel background color:

```
<your label name>.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

Change the UILabel text color

```
<your label name>.textColor = UIColor.green
```